# Custom product import script break after 1 product import!

Tags: magento-1.9, php, csv

I am using custom product import script to import the simp0le products. I have uploaded almost 40k products on the website.

But now, only 1 product import and then the script stop.

What is the wrong in my code or any other issue?

I have created customscript.php on the magento root

Below is my Script:

```
<?php  
error_reporting(0);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 20000);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento

umask(0);

    //Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(0)); 
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $data = glob("customupload/*.csv");   

    $fileList = array();
    foreach ($data as $file) {
        $fileList[filemtime($file)] = $file;
    }
    ksort($fileList);
    $myarray = array();
    foreach($fileList as $key => $val){
        $myarray[] = $val;
    }
    $list=array();
    if(count($myarray)){

    /*This will create an array of associative arrays with the first row column headers as the keys.*/
    $csv_map = array_map('str_getcsv', file($myarray[count($myarray)-1]));
    $list = explode('/', $myarray[count($myarray)-1]);
    array_walk($csv_map, function(&$a) use ($csv_map) {
        $a = array_combine($csv_map[0], $a);
    });

    array_shift($csv_map); # remove column header
    /*End*/

    $message = '';
    $count   = 1;

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $prodCol = array();
        foreach($productCollection as $productsku){
            $prodCol[] = $productsku['sku'];
        } 
    foreach($csv_map as $data){ 
        if(in_array($data['sku'], $prodCol)){
            $rowNo = $count+1;
            echo '<b>"'.$data['sku'].'"</b>'.' sku is already exists in admin. Please check csv <b>row number : '.$rowNo.'</b><br/>'; 
            $count++; continue;
        } 
        else{
            try {

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

            $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                            ->setType('catalog_product')
                            ->getTypeId();
            $attributeSetName   = $data['attribute set'];
            $attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                                    ->getCollection()
                                    ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                                    ->getFirstItem()
                                    ->getAttributeSetId();

            $product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId); // need to look this up 

            $product->setTaxClassId(0); // taxable goods

            $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search

            $product->setStatus(1); // enabled

            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)); 

            //$product->setStoreId(1);  

            $product->setTypeId('simple');

            $product->setWarranty('Lifetime');

            // assign product to the default website
            //$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));  


            // configure stock
            $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // use global config ?
                'manage_stock'            => 0, // should we manage stock or not?
                'is_in_stock'             => 1,
                'qty'                     => 10
            ));  
            //echo $data['image'];exit;

            //set category

            $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $data['Category'])->getFirstItem();

            $cat1= $_category->getId();

            $expcategory = explode('/',$data['sub category']); 

            $allsubcatid = array();

            foreach($expcategory as $_cat2) 
            {

                $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $_cat2)->getFirstItem();

                $allsubcatid[] = $_category->getId(); 

            } 
            $product->setCategoryIds(array($cat1,$allsubcatid));

            /* $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
            $attributeValue = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                            ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
                            ->setStoreFilter(0, false);
             foreach($attributeValue as $option)    
            {
                if (strtolower($option['value']) == strtolower($data['manufacturer'])) {
                    $manufacturer =  $option['option_id'];
                }
            } */
            // finally set custom data

            foreach($data as $key => $val){ 
                if($key != 'Category'){
                    $capitalword = ucwords(trim($key));
                    $remove_hyphen = str_replace(' ','',trim($capitalword)); 
                    $setdata = $remove_hyphen; 
                    $setdatas = set.$setdata; 
                    $product->$setdatas($val); 
                }
            }
            //$product->setManufacturer($manufacturer);

            $mediaArray = array(
                'thumbnail'   => $data['image'],
                'small_image' => $data['image'],
                'image'       => $data['image'],
            );

            // Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
            $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/product/';
            foreach ( $mediaArray as $imagetype => $fileName ) {

                $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
                if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
                    try {

                        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imagetype, false, false);

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
                }
            }
            //echo $product->getSelect(); 
            $product->save();

            }catch (Exception $e) {

                Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'configurableProductsDataError.log', true);
            }
        }
        $count++;
        $c .= $count."<br>"; 
        if($count ==1){ break; } 
    }

        echo "Success";
}

?>
 <?php

rename("customupload/".$list[1], "customupload/uploaded/".$list[1]);
?>
```

below columns are using in the csv:

```
attribute set
Category    
sub category    
sku 
description 
short description   
name    
price   
image   
weight
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think it might be? Did the script stop with any error? Did you check logs? are you running the php script straight on the server? Why are you using a custom import?

Comment: I have created customscript.php on the magento root

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the blank page.

Comment: check your server error logs and also the magento error logs at var/log/system.log for information

Comment: Issue has been fixed. I have replaced code:

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

by 

 Mage::app('english');

Answer (score 2):

NOt sure what should do following peace of code

```
if ($count == 1) {
        break;
    }
```

Probably this is the cause

Comment: last week, I have uploaded more than 40k products then it was working. Same issue after commenting that code.